# Почему на разных страницах с одинаковой стрктурой не парсится simple_html_dom?

Tags: php

Пытаюсь спарсить каталог товаров со старого сайта на новый (т.к. доступ к старой бд утерян). Структура рубрик каталога абсолютно одинаковая, CSS-классы и айдишники абсолютно те же. Но почему-то в одной из рубрик товары парсятся, а в другой нет.
Как такое может быть? Вообще, что может мешать парсингу?
pS
Вот структура html в рубрике, где всё нормально

```
<div class="welcome">
            <div class="breadcrumb"><a href="/">Главная</a> / <a href="/selection">Подбор аккумулятора</a> / <a href="/selection/car">Легковые</a> / <a href="/selection/car/7" class="active">AUDI</a></div>                                                <h1>Подбор аккумулятора</h1>
            <div class="item-list"><ul class="selection selection-3"><li class="first"><a href="/selection/car/7/95">100 (43, C2)</a></li>
```

[100 (44, 44Q, C3)](/selection/car/7/96)

[100 (4A, C4)](/selection/car/7/97)

а вот рубрика где косяк

```
 <div class="welcome">
            <div class="breadcrumb"><a href="/">Главная</a> / <a href="/selection">Подбор аккумулятора</a> / <a href="/selection/car">Легковые</a> / <a href="/selection/car/1" class="active">ALFA ROMEO</a></div>                                                <h1>Подбор аккумулятора</h1>
            <div class="item-list"><ul class="selection selection-3"><li class="first"><a href="/selection/car/1/1">145 (930)</a></li>
```

[146 (930)](/selection/car/1/2)

[147 (937)](/selection/car/1/3)

Самое интересное, что когда я просто пытаюсь взять кусок html по классу .welcome, в первом случае у меня выводится весь innertext, а во втором - только заголовок, и хлебные крошки. Списка марок авто - нет((

Comment: чудес не бывает, где то есть различия.

Comment: @teran так вот именно, что в том куске, который я пытаюсь спарсить, различий нет! Есть различия в начале страницы, но я и не привязываюсь к родителям, я сразу ищу список товаров.

Comment: Причём прикольно, если я например тупо попытаюсь спарсить все ссылки по тегу <a>, то в рубрике, где всё нормально, спарсятся все ссылки, а в рубрике, где косяк - только ссылки из верхнего меню! Такое впечатление, что после шапки сайта в данной рубрике что-то есть, что не даёт дальше смотреть DOM. Хотя видимых различий в html страниц нет.

Comment: дак может и нет. вы просмотрите исходный текст страницы. возможно там данные аяксом загружаются.

Comment: Copy XPath в браузере пробовал делать? Оба совпадают 1:1?

Comment: @teran обе рубрики из одной базы одним движком достаются, и в одной аякс, а в другой нет? Так не бывает)))

Comment: @Nsk решил сделать Copy XPath через гуглохром, и таки не сделал)) Потому что обалдел. В рубрике Ауди есть список моделей, а в рубрике Альфа ромео - пустая страница. Я уже ничего не понимаю. Файрфокс всё нормально отображает.

Comment: Если по простому селектору `a` не выбираются все ссылки со страницы, значит их там нет.

Comment: @teran вот я выше ответил. Хром вообще показывает какие-то чудеса.

Comment: файрфокс в инспекторе отображает текущий загруженный DOM а не исходный код страницы. чтобы его просмотреть, ткните в саму страницу и выберите Исходный код страницы.

Comment: вот нормальная страница http://avtoakb.kz/selection/car/7 а вот косяковая http://avtoakb.kz/selection/car/1, проверьте плиз кто-нибудь... уже совсем моск кипит

Comment: @teran и так и так смотрел - всё в норме в файрфоксе

Comment: "косяковая" пустая вообще

Comment: @teran ну не вообще, шапка подвал есть. А в файрфоксе она не пустая. Как так?

Comment: ну шапка то есть. вас то контент интересует а не шапка ведь?